# Building JSON Array from CSV column with multiple values [Python]

Tags: python, json, csv

I've new to coding and I'm trying to build a script for automating cisco DNAC ip pools creation, the goal is to read a CSV file and build a json body to post into dnac, I've this working fine, but not bullet proof, as some fields are arrays and I'm unable to read multiple values from a single column due to the commas.

What I'm trying to achieve now is to pass from the CSV multiple values from a single column to a JSON array on the code, if this column has only one value, then the object creation is successful, however if it has more fields in the CSV it fails. In the other hand, if I make this field static with the two value separated by a comma it runs successful, so the problem must reside on the way to read from the CSV, which I'm nowhere near the solution.

Here's what the CSV read block looks like:

```
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)

        for row in csvReader:
            # GET Site ID from each row in the CSV file
            site = row["Site"]
            url = "https://" + dnac + "/dna/intent/api/v1/site?name=" + str(site)

            payload = {}
            headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'x-auth-token': auth_token
            }

            response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
            data = response.json()
            site_id = data["response"][0]["id"]

            url = "https://" + dnac + "/dna/intent/api/v1/reserve-ip-subpool/" + site_id

            # Build JSON body from CSV file, read columns named after the JSON field
            payload = json.dumps({
                "name": row["name"],
                "type": row["type"],
                "ipv4GlobalPool": row["ipv4GlobalPool"],
                "ipv4PrefixLength": row["ipv4PrefixLength"],
                "ipv4Subnet": row["ipv4Subnet"],
                "ipv4GateWay": row["ipv4GateWay"],
                "ipv4DhcpServers": [
                    row["ipv4DhcpServers"]
                ],
                "ipv4DnsServers": [
                    row["ipv4DnsServers"]
                ]
            })
            # Post JSON body to DNAC API
            response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
```

On the fields `ipv4DhcpServers` and `ipv4DnsServers` is where the multiple values must fall, and for me the challenge is how can I pass it from this CSV (sample below).

```
name,type,ipv4GlobalPool,ipv4PrefixLength,ipv4Subnet,ipv4DhcpServers,ipv4DnsServers,ipv4GateWay,Site
teste41,generic,172.16.0.0/12,24,172.31.41.0,172.26.0.147,172.26.0.147,172.31.41.254,Global/EMEAR/SiteA
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had help from a colleague of mine and the solution for this problem was way more easy than I thought, here's how the payload looked like in the end:

```
            payload = json.dumps({
                "name": row["name"],
                "type": row["type"],
                "ipv4GlobalPool": row["ipv4GlobalPool"],
                "ipv4PrefixLength": row["ipv4PrefixLength"],
                "ipv4Subnet": row["ipv4Subnet"],
                "ipv4GateWay": row["ipv4GateWay"],
                "ipv4DhcpServers": row["ipv4DhcpServers"].split(" "),
                "ipv4DnsServers": row["ipv4DnsServers"].split(" ")
```

We removed the dict below `ipv4DhcpServers` and `ipv4DnsServers` to make it just a single dict (as I was nesting them) and placed split at the end to look for spaces on that CSV column.